# Almacenar una Imagen en MariaDB desde python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, imagen, mariadb

Hola amigos tengo un problema con MariaDB y es el sigueinte estoy tratando de almacenar una imagen en la base de datos para despues volverla a leer y me esta presentando un error mysql, tengo una conexion a la base de datos donde envio como actualización una foto en la ultima columna algo asi:

```
def ModColaborador(self, url, cedula):
    self.__init__()
    foto = self.convertirFoto(url)
    self.sql = 'update usuario set url_imagen={} where cedula={}'.format(foto, cedula)
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(self.sql)
        self.connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    self.closedb()

def convertirFoto(self, foto):
    with open(foto, 'rb') as f:
        img = f.read()
        print(type(img))
    return img
foto = r"C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\001.PyImage_Project\Alcoholimetro\alcoholimetro\dataset\12345\00004.png"
modificar = dbconexion()
modificar.ModColaborador(foto, 12345)
```

y lo ejecuto y me sale el siguiente error

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\\x1b\\xd2>h\\x16\\xcf\\xbdV\\xf9tKX\\xfbqt\\x0e6{5N\\xf1vNZ\\xcc\\x01:\\xaf\\xdc\\xea\\x92\\...' at line 1")
```

No encuentro la forma de almacenar la imagen espero me puedan ayudar de antemano Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué el error dice MariaDB?

Comment: Siempre me e preguntado eso sopongo que es mariaDB estoy utilizando xampp en windows para hacer esas pruebas

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para cambiar las referencias a mysql por MariaDB, a fin de evitar confusiones.

Comment: No deberías guardar el url de la imagen en vez de la imagen?. Sino, una opcion para guardar la imagen es codificar sus bytes en base64 con [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html).

Comment: Ahora me retorna el error asi: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'iVBORw0KGt...' at line 1")

Comment: Hola. Cómo está definida la tabla donde quieres guardar la imagen? Las columnas y su tipo de dato

Comment: Hola. te recomiendo guardar tu imagen en formato BLOB, y revisar el tipo de datos que acepta la columna que guardará la imagen en tu base de datos

Comment: Prueba cambiar esto `self.sql = 'update usuario set url_imagen={} where cedula={}'.format(foto, cedula)` por esto `self.sql = f"update usuario set url_imagen={foto} where cedula='{cedula}'"`

Comment: El tipo de datos es BLOB y en acotejamiento no tiene ninguno es el mismo acotejamiento sierto?

Comment: Realice el cambio que me dijiste Luis Felipe y no sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: sí pero creo que tu query falla al indicarle el `where`, ya que segun veo estás haciendo `where cedula = foo-bar` en vez de  `where cedula = 'foo-bar'`.

Comment: Asi realice le cambio me sigue dicendo el error 1064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos la mejor opcion es almacenar la url de una imagen y remplazar las barras invertidas para que mysql no genere errores barra invertida gracias a todos por las ayudas.